# Twitter Bootstrap alerts does not gets close in the model

Tags: alert, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the Twitter Bootstrap alerts in the model.

It is displayed fine but close functionality for the alert does not works properly, when we click on the close link of the alert, my model gets close.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: do you have any sample code which illustrates the issue. this question is very difficult to answer with no detail to work with

Comment: @AntonyScott:  My code is some what big to post here. but I have tried using very simple code (just copy-paste from [link](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) ) but is not working means close link of the alert box does not close the alert instead of this it will close the model directly. 
Have you tried this kind of issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/838
 or http://jsfiddle.net/thegreyjoy/yXswA/7/

We just need to change the class of the alert box when it is used in the model.

:)

Comment: As this question is ans when I am using bootstrap version 1 but from now on as there is latest version of the bootstrap thay have given handy code as

 <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a> 

Means we 'data-dismiss' option to close 'alert' , 'modal' etc.

Please chk here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#alerts
OR
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals as
<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>